# How to get boost filesystem to see v120 of the .lib file and not v110

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to get boost::filesystem to compile.  The system sees the filesystem.hpp file but it can't link and gives the error message

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

I tried building the boost libs with the 1_55 version I'm using but it built the vc120 version and not the vc110 version. This is strange because I'm using the same 1_55_0 source for the #include files and the b2 build so I'm not clear why it's looking for vc110 in the #include and building vc120.  I've tried including the .lib file in the VC12 Project settings in Addt'l Dependencies and Addt'l Includes sections but it doesn't make a difference.  Same error.  I'm using VC2012.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

vc110 is the default platform toolset of Visual Studio 2012. You can set it in the project properties/Configuration Properties/General/Platform Toolset.

Boost will not build with vc120 with VC2012 because VC2012 cannot use vc120 - I'm not sure if it's possible to make it use the vc120 at all. Usually vc120 means Visual Studio 2013 (and Win8).

I would do the following things:

1. Check if your filesystem project is set to vc110 (in General/Platform Toolset)
2. Check if the lib is in Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies
3. Check if the path to the lib is in VC++ Directories

Boost HAS to build vc110, for whatever reasons it builds vc120, it shouldn't. If it does anyway, set the project settings to vc110.

I hope that helps..

Comment: Gerald, thanks!  I'll give that a try and post back.  Boost is building the 120. Here's the file name: boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.lib  I'm not sure why it's doing this but there are some things I can look at to see.  That's essentially the crux of the problem now.  If the 110s will build then the filesystem include file should recognize 110 lib file.  I'll post again here what I find.